# Email app crashes if a photo is not available for attachment

Tags: android, email, android-intent, android-camera

My app has the option to take a photo, which will later be attached into an email. It works fine.

The problem is, it crashes if there's no photo taken. Any idea how I can fix this?

Here's my button code, in case it comes handy somehow.

```
Button SendMail = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendemail);
SendMail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"somemail@mail.com"});
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject");
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "body");
        emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Choose an Email client"));
    }
});
```

Comment: Umm, put `emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);` inside an `if-statement` to check if `imageUri` is valid/not empty/not null?

Comment: I tried to add an if (imageUri != null) but it doesn't work.

Comment: Before that, could you put the LogCat when the app crashes?

Comment: I tried disabling the button and enabling it after the img was captured, it worked.